# php how do you retrieve post from database?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I know this question has been asked many times, but I can't ever make it work for my code, please bear with me, I'm pretty new to `php` `oop` `pdo`.

**My objective**

Retrieve a post title stored in the database using `php` `oop` `pdo`

**The Problem**

It returns this error:

```
Undefined property: PDOStatement::$fetch
```

I looked at the [php docs about `pdostatement`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

I learned `crud` from [this tutorial](http://www.codingcage.com/2015/04/php-pdo-crud-tutorial-using-oop-with.html), but i can't translate it with my code,

**Here is my code:**

**Crud.php**

```
<?php

include 'connection.php';

class Crud{
    
    private $db;
    
    
    function __construct($pdo)
    {
        $this->db = $pdo;
    }
    
    public function create_post($post_title, $post_content)
    {
        try{
            $query = "INSERT INTO posts(post_title, post_content) VALUES (:ptitle, :pbody)";
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bindParam(':ptitle', $post_title);
            $stmt->bindParam(':pbody', $post_content);
            $stmt->execute();
            
            return $stmt;
        }
        
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            $e->getMessage();
        }
        
    }

    public function setQuery($sql)
    {
        try{
            $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $query->execute();

            return $query;

        }

        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    
}
```

**Index.php** (Where I want to posts to post)

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once 'inc/Crud.php';

?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Welcome to house</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is the home page</h1>



<?php

$crud = new Crud($pdo);

$sql =  "SELECT * FROM posts";

if($result=$crud->setQuery($sql) )
{
    if($count = $result->fetch)
    {
        echo '<p>', $count, '</p>';

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            echo $row['post_title'], '<br>';
        }
    }
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm pretty confused. Any recommendations and best practices (for `php5` and up)?

Comment: Should stick to MVC methodologies using dependency injection and singleton design patterns and keeping models and controllers separate.

Comment: i know, but im practicing CRUD, just want to get to confidently know how to show posts, before i dive into an mvc structure

Comment: fetch is a method, not a property do ```->fetch()``` but regarding your code i guess you want the numbers of row so its ```->fetchColumn()``` https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php 
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php

Comment: i was able to retrieve a number, but not the post title

Comment: @olibiaz so i figured something out, 

$count = $result->fetchColumn(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)

works, you steered me in the right direction

however i have an error

 Call to undefined method PDOStatement::fetch_assoc()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the help guys you all steered me in the right direction.

here is the correct code

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once 'inc/Crud.php';

?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Welcome to house</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is the home page</h1>



<?php

$crud = new Crud($pdo);

$sql =  "SELECT * FROM posts";

if($result=$crud->setQuery($sql) )
{
    if($count = $result->fetchColumn(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        echo '<p>', $count, '</p>';

        while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            echo $row['post_title'], '<br>';
        }
    }
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`fetch` is a function, not a property

Use this instead:

```
    if($count = $result->fetch())
                              ^^
```

Comment: tried it and got

 Call to undefined method PDOStatement::fetch_assoc()

Comment: Because there is no method fetch_assoc. You can check the docs here: http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php

Comment: i have a hard time understanding the documentation, i would appreciate if  it can be broken down to understand.